# AJAX module not submitting the form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am having a problem with this JavaScript, it's reloading the page and not submitting the form!

JavaScript:

```
var xmlHttp
function GetXmlHttpObject(){
  var objXMLHttp=null;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    objXMLHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
    objXMLHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  return objXMLHttp
}
function ajax_module(){
  xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
  if (xmlHttp==null) {
    alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
    return
  }
  xmlHttp.open('POST', 'save.php');
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
  xmlHttp.send('user='+document.form1.user1.value+'&text='+document.form1.text1.value);
  document.form1.test1.value = '';
  document.form1.test1.focus();
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" onsubmit="ajax_module(); return false;">
    <textarea name='text1'></textarea> 
    <input type='hidden' name='user1' value='$user' />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What does Firebug say?

And I suggest you use some Javascript framework (jQuery, Prototype) to handle the AJAX requests.

Comment: when i use input in place of textarea it works some times ...
and i really don't want to use heavy JavaScript for this

Comment: If it just submits the form by refreshing, something is wrong in your ajax_module() function.

Comment: im thinking maybe user1 is null because it's not closed. i think that would only be true for xhtml though. or just the function is altogether wrong

Comment: thanks guys for taking time for my problem i sorted out my self ;)
thanks again! the problem was in the ajax module and now i have also edited the above example too

Comment: If you've figured out the answer to this question, please close it.  Also, if you use a popular JavaScript library servered by Google's CDN, it's not "heavy" at all.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check that no errors are occurring within `ajax_module`. If there are any, it will never get to `return false` and won't stop the `onsubmit`.

If you have Firebug or a similar debugger available, set breakpoints within `ajax_module`. Otherwise, add a `try`/`catch` right inside `ajax_module`:

```
function ajax_module() {
  try {
    /* place what you already have here */
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

You also commented that text inputs usually work. This may be due to newlines being allowed in textareas, which you aren't currently encoding.

Whether that's the cause or not, it's probably a good idea to encode the values anyways.

```
xmlHttp.send('user=' + encodeURIComponent(document.form1.user1.value) + 
            '&text=' + encodeURIComponent(document.form1.text1.value));
```

For more info, check out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp.

An alternative would be [`escape`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) -- though, note the character differences described on each page.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's the missing self-closing tag on the user input? Is there a JavaScript error?